# Grunt watch with livereload after javascript concat is loading page with the previous change not latest

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, livereload, grunt-contrib-watch

I'm working on an Angular application. I'm struggling with grunt-contrib-watch and livereload working correctly after I run other tasks on my css and js files.

Basically I do the following:

1. JsHint, Concatenate & uglify the js on change.
2. Run autoprefixer on css change.

Both of these create new files which I include on my index page.

When those new files are created, I want them to be live reloaded in my browser.

The following is my Gruntfile.js:

```
grunt.initConfig({
  pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
  autoprefixer: {
    dist: {
        files: {
            'webapp/assets/css/build/rm.css': 'webapp/assets/css/pre/rm.css'
        }
    },
    options: {
        browsers: ['Explorer >= 8', '> 1%', 'last 2 versions', 'Firefox ESR', 'Opera 12.1']
    }
},
concat: {   
    dist: {
        src: [
            'webapp/app.js',  // This specific file
            'webapp/shared/**/*.js', // All the shared angular files
            'webapp/specific/**/*.js', // All the page specific angular files
            '!webapp/shared/tests/*.js', //Remove tests
            '!webapp/specific/*/tests/*.js' //Remove tests
        ],
        dest: 'webapp/assets/libs/production.js',
    }
},
uglify: {
    options: {
      banner: '/*! <%= pkg.name %> <%= grunt.template.today("yyyy-mm-dd") %> */\n'
    },
    build: {
        src: 'webapp/assets/libs/production.js',
        dest: 'webapp/assets/libs/production.min.js'
    }
},
jshint: {
    options: {
        reporter: require('jshint-stylish'),
        predef: [ "angular", "describe", "beforeEach", "module", "inject", "expect", "it" ]
    },
    target: ['webapp/app.js', 'webapp/shared/**/*.js', 'webapp/specific/**/*.js']
},
watch: {
    scripts: {
        files: ['webapp/app.js', 'webapp/shared/**/*.js', 'webapp/specific/**/*.js', 
                '!webapp/shared/tests/*.js', '!webapp/specific/*/tests/*.js'], 
        tasks: ['jshint', 'concat', 'uglify'],
    },
    styles: {
        files: ['webapp/assets/css/pre/*.css'],
        tasks: ['autoprefixer'],
    },
    livereload: {
        options: {
          livereload: true,
        },
        files: ['webapp/assets/libs/production.js',
                'webapp/assets/libs/production.min.js',
                'webapp/assets/css/build/rm.css', 
                'webapp/shared/**/*.html', 
                'webapp/specific/**/*.html', 
                'webapp/index.html']
    },        
  }
```

});

In my index.html I include the built css and production.min.js files:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/build/rm.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/libs/production.min.js"></script>
```

I have tried live reload with both the Chrome extension and adding the script tag to my HTML

My watch output recognizes that the production.min.js & build/rm.css post-processed files have changed.

I'm experiencing the two following problems:

1. For both my Javascript & HTML files, it is live reloaded, but it has
   a change from one time prior, not the latest change.  That is, it lags by one change.
2. My CSS is not live reloaded at all.

Before I added the JSHint, concat, and uglify tasks livereload seemed to work correctly.

Can anyone tell me what I have done wrong? Is this a time lag problem?

Comment: Sorry is this is off-topic a bit, but what is your OS and browser? Live-reload consistently crashes on me with Windows 8.1 and Chrome

Comment: I am using Windows 8.1 and Chrome also.  It isn't crashing, but it also is not quite working.

Comment: Did you manage to fix it?